# Where can I find a reference list/chart that shows included root certificate authorities included in each version Java VM/JDK?

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

Where can I find a reference list/chart that shows the included root ssl certs included in each version Java VM/JDK?. Meaning-- for every version of the sdk/jre.
This info is generally in the  \java ver\lib\security directory. But I am looking for a chart/list that shows all version of Java.
I am *NOT* trying to find out how to know the certs for a VM that I have. Meaning, shows the certs for a specific VM I have installed locally. What I am looking for is an online reference that shows what root ssl certs Sun/Oracle 'baked in' to the Java VM for every version of Java. This question has nothing to do with adding certs to a keystore, or web browsers, or how to obtain a certificate from a third party.

As a second related question (kinda); does anyone have the same info above but for the 'baked in' root certs that are for all popular browsers and versions?
Cert vendors usually scatter this info on their sites. But what I need is a simple chart that you can see: for a browser/version-- what roots certs are baked in.

Cheers!
Will--

---

11/8/2013 11am update:

I did more research on this and found no place online that has this info. So I started to think about it from the perspective of how it might be possible to get this info yourself in a non-painful way. Here's is where i ended up:

1) Get access to all versions of the cacerts file from some kind of sun/ora source code repository. Then affiliate those file versions somehow with what jdk version they would have shipped with. Then programatically use the keytool to obtain all the certs for each version of the file. Voila... the data I seek.
But-- I was unable to find any repository git/subversion/cvs/blah that has the cacerts file revision history all the way back.

2) Use the newest java 8 bundled cert file as a starting point, and then use the date each cert was added (keytool provides that) as a way to figure out what would have been there at any moment in time in the past (i.e.: older java versions).
But-- This wont work. Because I found out sometimes certs are removed. That is, some certs that would have been in the 1.6_x jdk don't get 're-upped' and included in later versions of the cert file. I actually proved this by diffing a 1.5_X certs file to a 1.6_x cert file. Technically I didn't diff the two files, I actually diffed that certs that were in the files.

3) Download all vers sdk (the whole darned thing) and essentially do the same thing as step 1 above. This might work, but is way painful. I didn't attempt this.

So... no love so far

Comment: Do you realize that just between versions 1.6 and 1.7, only counting the Sun/Oracle HotSpot JVM (and ignoring the dozens of other implemetnations), there are around 60 java releases?  Such a chart would be HUGE.

Comment: Understood. But it's very important information to have in an enterprise environment. Generally there isn't big movement in new third party certs orgs that get put in the default keystore between the small JM updates.

Comment: For example, between jdk1.6.0_20 and jdk1.6.0_21 there were no changes at all to the included carts in the keystore

Comment: This question might be better suited toward superuser.stackexchange.com, as it is not really about a program that is primarily used for programming, but rather an environment that programs run in or otherwise utilize. Furthermore, the question is asking how to do something specific with the environment and not how to manipulate it or make use of it in another piece of software. If this question had content regarding how to retrieve the information via code, then it would be best suited here.